# iTextSharp is generating single page pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, itext

Converting Binary "data:image/jpeg;base64," to pdf but not getting correct output, my binary string is very long which content 10 pages of pdf, Image url i am getting full image, but when i am generation ToBase64String to pdf then only one page

```
string folderPath = Server.MapPath("~/ImageFiles/");
    WebBrowser webrowse = sender as WebBrowser;        
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(webrowse.Width, webrowse.Height, PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb565);     
    webrowse.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, webrowse.Bounds);    
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    bitmap.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    byte[] strbytes = stream.ToArray();
    imgscreenshot.Visible = true;
    imgscreenshot.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(strbytes);
    string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(strbytes);          
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
    iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageBytes);

    using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 88f, 88f, 10f, 10f);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
        document.Open();
        document.Add(image);
        document.Close();
        byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        memoryStream.Close();

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Image.pdf");
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.End();
    }
```

In below Image is single page generated and not in center position also and arround 10 pages should come but that is not generated

[image]

Comment: If you want different parts of a bitmap image to be displayed on different pages, you have to add each section separately. If you don't want page margin, set it to 0.

Comment: Can you answer in code please. @mkl

Comment: I have very big single image that image have height around 10000 webrowser.Height = 10000;. @mk

Comment: *"I have very big single image that image have height around 10000"* - and you want to spread that height over multiple pages. Do you know at which heights the image shall be cut? Or shall there simply be as much as fits onto a page?

Comment: Ya i have set image height 10000 it is fix webrowser.Height = 10000;., because i have application form. @mkl

Comment: Do you know at which heights the image shall be cut? Or shall there simply be as much as fits onto a page?